# How to fix the error in the following code in Python and Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, embeddings

I am unable to figure out the problem with the code (see below). I am also providing error trace after the code. Goal of the code is to use a dataset (with numerical and categorical variables) to predict some variables via neural network (Multi-node output). For the categorical variables, I am using Embedding (entity-embedding) technique.

```
# Integer encoding for categories so that it can be fed into a Keras Embedding layer
# Keras Embedding layer only accepts interger arrays and NOT STRINGS
# Create a label (category) encoder object

LE = {}
# Fit the encoder to the pandas column
for cat in cat_model_vars:
    LE[cat] = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    LE[cat].fit(modelDF[cat])
    modelDF[f"{cat}_enc"] = LE[cat].transform(modelDF[cat])

# imports the required modules from keras and other packages

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate, Reshape, Dropout
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding

inputs = []
embeddings = []

# for categorical variables
for cat in cat_model_vars:
    inp = Input(shape=(1,))
    inputs.append(inp)
    emb = Embedding(cat_sizes[cat]+1,cat_embedding_size[cat], input_length=1,name=f"{cat}_embedding")(inp)
    emb = Reshape(target_shape=(cat_embedding_size[cat],))(emb)
    embeddings.append(emb)

# for continuous/numerical variables

inp_num = Input(shape=(len(num_model_vars),),name='cont_vars')
#emb_num = Dense(10)(inp_num)
inputs.append(inp_num)

embeddings.append(inp_num)

# concatenate the embeddings, this is going to be input to our model
output = Concatenate()(embeddings)

# Model is plain regression for the numerical vars 

# regression model
x = Dense(50, activation = 'relu')(output)

x = Dense(6, activation = 'linear')(x)

regModel = Model(inputs,x)

regModel.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse','mae'])

regModel.fit([modelDF.A_enc, modelDF.B_enc, modelDF.C_enc, modelDF.D_enc, modelDF[num_model_vars]],modelDF[num_model_vars],batch_size=50,epochs=50)
```

I am getting the following error which I couldn't decipher.

```
Epoch 1/50
2020-06-24 17:09:23.223086: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Invalid argument: indices[5,0] = 5 is not in [0, 3)
         [[{{node if_type_embedding_3/embedding_lookup}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-390-71f7c8631f63>", line 1, in <module>
    regModel.fit([modelDF.A_enc, modelDF.B_enc, modelDF.C_enc, modelDF.D_enc, modelDF[num_model_vars]],modelDF[num_model_vars],batch_size=50,epochs=50)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1239, in fit
    validation_freq=validation_freq)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 196, in fit_loop
    outs = fit_function(ins_batch)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 3740, in __call__
    outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1081, in __call__
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1121, in _call_impl
    return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1224, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 511, in call
    ctx=ctx)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from

InvalidArgumentError:  indices[5,0] = 5 is not in [0, 3)
     [[node if_type_embedding_3/embedding_lookup (defined at /opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_6257]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

Any idea what is wrong with this code?
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.